# HTTP CONNECT handshake over TSL/SSL

Tags: apache, http, ssl, nginx, https

My understanding of HTTP tunnel is that the client sends an `HTTP CONNECT` **in clear text** to establish a tunnel, which is then encrypted by the client and the destination server. Is there a way to send this `HTTP CONNECT` handshake encrypted?

Comment: The proxy needs to be reached over an HTTPS connection, and it should work. Or let the proxy terminate the TLS connection. But of little benefit in both cases: inside the TLS handshake the SNI (which will be basically the hostname present in the `CONNECT`) will be in the clear, so a passive listener will get the same information anyway.